# Unity 2d win condition , game similar to TicTacToe

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, 2d, conditional-statements

i'm creating a little game, and I've a problem. 
Each players have 3 pieces. They've to put their pieces in case , like a Tic Tac Toe board. 
The victory conditions are same than Tic Tac Toe. But in this game, you only have 3 pieces, and you can move them on the board , and after you placed  yours pieces on the board, one after one.

The pieces can only move from a case to an adjacent case. 
My problem is for the verification , the victory condition. 
I've a "Board" , and i wanted to know if i can do thoses victory conditions with the position of the pieces on the board , or i cant ?

Example:  If the 3 allies pieces are in x1,y1 x2 y2, and x3,y3, u have win. 
Or if the 3 pieces are in 3 others objects, you win.

If u want more information about this, i can told more, so i thought about this tutorial code in Unity, about the Tic Tac Toe, but i didnt used panel.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

public Text[] buttonList;

private string playerSide;

void Awake ()
{
    SetGameControllerReferenceOnButtons();
    playerSide = "X";
}

void SetGameControllerReferenceOnButtons ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Length; i++)
    {
        buttonList[i].GetComponentInParent<GridSpace>().SetGameControllerReference(this);

    }
}

public string GetPlayerSide ()
{
    return playerSide;
}

public void EndTurn ()
{
    if (buttonList [0].text == playerSide && buttonList [1].text == playerSide && buttonList [2].text == playerSide)
    {
        GameOver();
    }
}

void GameOver ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Length; i++)
    {
        buttonList[i].GetComponentInParent<Button>().interactable = false;
    }
}
```

}

Sorry for my english guys and if my explications are too bad ^^ .

Comment: As far as i understand the win condition for your game is the same as for a TicTacToe game. You have a tutorial for TicTacToe? Check how it is done there.  Otherwise my thinking here would be: The board knows all the combinations of positions with which it is possible to win. After each player turn check if all positions of any of these combinations is taken by the same player.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no much win cases, you can make every win condition as an *ArrayList* and control it with *ArrayList.Contains* in an *if condition*.